# Google Chart All series on a given axis must be of the same data type confusing error

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, charts, google-visualization

I'm confuse with this error message when I run my google chart. This is my code on generating the chart.

```
function (resultVal) {
    var arrMain = new Array();//[];
    for (var i = 0; i < resultVal.length; i++) {
        var arr = new Array(resultVal[i].ScaleMin, resultVal[i].CountryNo, resultVal[i].ScaleMax, resultVal[i].Currency);
        arrMain.push(arr);
        }
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'ScaleMin', label: 'ScaleMin' });
        data.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'CountryNo', label: 'CountryNo' });
        data.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'ScaleMax', label: 'ScaleMax' });
        data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Currency', label: 'Currency' });
        data.addRows(arrMain);
        var options = {
        'title': 'Salad Entry',
        'width': 800,
        'height': 600
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
        $.ajax({
        url: "SaladEntry/SaveToLocal",
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'jsonData': chart.getImageURI() },
        success: function (ret) {
        alert(ret);
        }
        });
        });
        chart.draw(data, options);
```

This is error message I receive when loading the chart.

[image]

And the list of array i set as the datasource of my chart.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can only use a `'string'` data type on the x-axis, or first column

unless it is being used as an annotation, tooltip, or other [column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available)

the following column is causing the issue

```
data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Currency', label: 'Currency' });
```

if you wanted to add currency as an annotation, then need to set the `role` property...

```
data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Currency', role: 'annotation' });
```

this would cause the value in the currency column to be displayed in a label,
as an annotation, above each point for the series column --> `'ScaleMax'`

column roles only apply to the series column they follow

each chart type has a specific [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#data-format) which lists what types each column may have

it's the same for all of the common charts, such as line, area, column, bar, etc...

**EDIT**

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', label: 'x'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'y'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
    data.addRow(['one', 1, 'color: green']);

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      legend: 'none'
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```